# Ribbon issue in SharePoint Internet and Intranet

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

We had done a change in AAM  for https to http traffic redirection in the LAN.

On to the continuation, we are facing an issue in our SharePoint portals. (i.e.) We could able to edit/modify a documents from the portal in Intranet(LAN). But whereas, when we try the same in Internet, the edit document ribbon is disabled and not accessible.

Note : From the permission perspective – The User have full control permission for sites / libraries.

If someone had faced this kind of an issue. Kindly help us.

Answer (score 1):

If you have customized the ribbon using JavaScript, try the following steps:

- Deploy those JavaScript files to the master page gallery. The master page gallery is preconfigured to allow access by anonymous users
- Also, check your JavaScript code, is it referencing a https resources?

If none of the above steps help, run [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) while browsing to the site. That should give you some hints as to what the issue might be.